# open MP - dot product

Tags: c, openmp

I am implementing parallel dot product in open MP

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>
#define SIZE 1000

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

  float u[SIZE], v[SIZE], dp,dpp;
  int i, j, tid;

  dp=0.0;
  for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
      u[i]=1.0*(i+1);
      v[i]=1.0*(i+2);
  }
  printf("\n values of u and v:\n");

  for (i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
      printf(" u[%d]= %.1f\t v[%d]= %.1f\n",i,u[i],i,v[i]);
  }
  #pragma omp parallel shared(u,v,dp,dpp) private (tid,i)
  {
      tid=omp_get_thread_num();

      #pragma omp for private (i)
      for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
          dpp+=u[i]*v[i];
          printf("thread: %d\n", tid);
      }
      #pragma omp critical
      {
          dp=dpp;
          printf("thread %d\n",tid);
      }


  }

  printf("\n dot product is %f\n",dp);

 }
```

I am starting it with: `pgcc -B -Mconcur -Minfo -o prog prog.c`

And result I get in console is:

```or-tag-here
33, Loop not parallelized: innermost 

39, Loop not vectorized/parallelized: contains call

48, Loop not vectorized/parallelized: contains call
```

What am I doing wrong?

From my side of view, everything looks Ok.

Comment: What do you mean wrong, it compiled successfully?  The call appears to be `printf`.

Comment: The messages you are seeing are not OpenMP informational messages.  You used -Mconcur, which means that you want the compiler to auto-concurrentize (or auto-parallelize) the code.  To use OpenMP the correct option is -mp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, a simple 1,000-element dot product does not have enough computational cost to justify multi-threading --- you will pay so much more in communication and synchronization costs than you will gain in performance that it is not worth it.

Secondly, it looks like you are computing the full dot product in each thread, not dividing the computation across multiple threads and combining the result at the end.

Here is an example of how to do vector dot products from https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#SHARED

```
#include <omp.h>

main ()
{
  int   i, n, chunk;
  float a[100], b[100], result;

  /* Some initializations */
  n = 100;
  chunk = 10;
  result = 0.0;
  for (i=0; i < n; i++) {
      a[i] = i * 1.0;
      b[i] = i * 2.0;
  }

  #pragma omp parallel for      \  
      default(shared) private(i)  \  
      schedule(static,chunk)      \  
      reduction(+:result)  

    for (i=0; i < n; i++)
        result += (a[i] * b[i]);

  printf("Final result= %f\n",result);
}
```

Basically, OpenMP is good for doing coarse-grained parallelism when you have large, expensive loops.  In general, when you are doing parallel programming, the larger the "chunks" of computation you can do before re-synchronizing, the better.  Especially as the number of cores grows, the communication and synchronization costs will grow.  Pretend that each synchronization (grabbing a new index or chunk of indexes to execute, entering a critical section, etc.) costs you 10ms, or 1M instructions to get a better idea of when/where/how to parallelize your code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is still the same as in your latest question. You are accumulating values in a variable and you must tell OpenMp how to do that:

```
#pragma omp for reduction(+: dpp)
for(size_t i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
  dpp += u[i]*v[i];
}
```

Use a loop-local variable for the index and that is all you need, forget about all the stuff that you are doing around that. If you want to see then what the compiler is doing of your code run it with -S and check the assembler output. This can be very instructive, because you then learn what simple statements like that amount to when they are parallelized.

And don't use `int` for loop indices. Sizes and stuff like that are `size_t`.

Comment: You don't have to use loop-local variables.  It can be declared private in a clause on the for directive or for that matter if the workshare for loop is in canonical form, then the loop index will be private by default.  Also, unless you are using OpenMP V3.0, you can not use size_t variables as the loop index.

Comment: @ejd, I didn't say "he'd have to". The form I gave is just the simplest form, concise and readable. If he can't use `size_t` the compiler will tell him, but this is the semantically correct index type for C.

Comment: while I don't know the pgcc compiler, most compilers don't give a very good error message when it comes to what is wrong with the canonical form of the workshare for of OpenMP. There is a good chance all the user will see is a message saying that there is something wrong with initialization, condition, and increment of the loop - leaving it to the user to figure out that the loop iteration variable can't be unsigned.